# Java - LinkedList Doubt

Tags: java, collections, queue

I need to create a FIFO queue. I was thinking in creating a LinkedList for that, because of it's native methods to remove and add. But my queue should have a fixed size, so how could I fix that size?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Override the add method to perform a check on the size of list before adding?

Comment: Is this HW? If so, please tag it as such. But what do you want to have happen if someone adds to your queue that exceeds the size?

Comment: No it's not HW it's a project I am making

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question/17325#17325

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing would be use one of the implementations of [java.util.Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) or [java.util.Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap an instance of a `LinkedList` in your own class, and control the size (composition). The downside (or upside, based on your preference) of this is that you can control which methods to explose, in this case `add` and `remove`. Another alternative is to extend `LinkedList` and override `add`/`remove` while controlling the size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain better what I need to do? I must control just the limit of the LinkedList so it don't pass a certain number while I add my stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have a fixed size, then you ought to use an ArrayList (or just an array) to back the FIFO....  Just keep a variable representing the index of the head, and a variable representing the index of the tail and move them around as you push and pop.

However, if this isn't homework, you should probably just use one of the many available Collections classes.  They do the job very well.